# How to start and stop campaigns in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, permissions, campaign, marketingcloudapi

The documentation 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/campaign.htm
mentions that a campaign can be started and stopped via SOAP APIs. Where can we find the Start and Stop permissions in our account? Also how can we get the customer Key of the campaign?